# Animate dashed SVG line

Tags: css, animation, svg, line

I would like to animate a **dashed line** in a SVG-file. The line should »grow« from 0 length to full length. All the methods I found are not suitable for me.

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve this?

That's the path in my svg file:

```
<path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M234.3,119
    c-31-0.7-95,9-128.7,50.8"/>
```

To animate the line as **straight** line i did:

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Of course, this is not working, when I want the line to be dashed.
Is there anybody who has an idea how to solve this?

That's my codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpZNJY

PS: I can't use two paths over each other to hide the path underneath because I'm having a coloured background.

Comment: Would you want to consider using Javascript for this animation?

Comment: Would be ok for me too. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I could put something to try. However, I have other commitments until late today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways to do this is with Javascript. It duplicates a path by creating a polyline.
Try the example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
polyline{
stroke-dasharray:8;
stroke:black;
fill:none;
stroke-width:1;
}

</style>


</head>
<body >
This builds a smooth/dashed polylines that replicates your paths.<br>
<button onClick=animateDashPaths()>Animate Paths</button><br>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 830 500" enable-background="new 0 0 830 500" xml:space="preserve">

<path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M234.3,119
c-31-0.7-95,9-128.7,50.8"/>

<!-- Vienna Dash  -->
<path id="pathVienna"  display="none"  stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M382.8,243.8
c2.9-36.1,15.8-110.3,110.1-145.4"/>

<!-- Budapest Dash  -->
<path id="pathBudapest" display="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M550.6,319.4
c34-2.7,109-2.1,174.8,50.5"/>

<!-- Salzburg Dash  -->
<path id="pathSalzburg" display="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M265,323
c21.5,12.1,57.2,39.5,60.7,85.1"/>

<!-- Tyrol Dash  -->
<path id="pathTyrol" display="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M147.8,319.5
 c-27.1,7-79.7,31.3-92.8,74.2"/>

</svg>

<script>
//---button---
function animateDashPaths()
{
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

//----Vienna----------------
var endLengthVienna=pathVienna.getTotalLength()
var lengthDeltaVienna=endLengthVienna/200
var polylineVienna=document.createElementNS(NS,"polyline")
Layer_1.appendChild(polylineVienna)
var pntListVienna=polylineVienna.points
var iTVienna=setInterval(drawPathVienna,5)
var cntVienna=0
function drawPathVienna()
{
   var len=lengthDeltaVienna*cntVienna++
   if(len<endLengthVienna)
   {
        var pnt=pathVienna.getPointAtLength(len)
        pntListVienna.appendItem(pnt)
   }
   else
      clearInterval(iTVienna)
}

//----Budapest----------------
var endLengthBudapest=pathBudapest.getTotalLength()
var lengthDeltaBudapest=endLengthBudapest/200
var polylineBudapest=document.createElementNS(NS,"polyline")
Layer_1.appendChild(polylineBudapest)
var pntListBudapest=polylineBudapest.points
var iTBudapest=setInterval(drawPathBudapest,5)
var cntBudapest=0
function drawPathBudapest()
{
   var len=lengthDeltaBudapest*cntBudapest++
   if(len<endLengthBudapest)
   {
        var pnt=pathBudapest.getPointAtLength(len)
        pntListBudapest.appendItem(pnt)
   }
   else
      clearInterval(iTBudapest)
}

//----Salzburg----------------
var endLengthSalzburg=pathSalzburg.getTotalLength()
var lengthDeltaSalzburg=endLengthSalzburg/200
var polylineSalzburg=document.createElementNS(NS,"polyline")
Layer_1.appendChild(polylineSalzburg)
var pntListSalzburg=polylineSalzburg.points
var iTSalzburg=setInterval(drawPathSalzburg,5)
var cntSalzburg=0
function drawPathSalzburg()
{
   var len=lengthDeltaSalzburg*cntSalzburg++
   if(len<endLengthSalzburg)
   {
        var pnt=pathSalzburg.getPointAtLength(len)
        pntListSalzburg.appendItem(pnt)
   }
   else
      clearInterval(iTSalzburg)
}

//----Tyrol----------------
var endLengthTyrol=pathTyrol.getTotalLength()
var lengthDeltaTyrol=endLengthTyrol/200
var polylineTyrol=document.createElementNS(NS,"polyline")
Layer_1.appendChild(polylineTyrol)
var pntListTyrol=polylineTyrol.points
var iTTyrol=setInterval(drawPathTyrol,5)
var cntTyrol=0
function drawPathTyrol()
{
   var len=lengthDeltaTyrol*cntTyrol++
   if(len<endLengthTyrol)
   {
        var pnt=pathTyrol.getPointAtLength(len)
        pntListTyrol.appendItem(pnt)
   }
   else
      clearInterval(iTTyrol)
}

}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works really great for me! But how can I loop through the function to animate all paths (#myPath1, #myPath2, …)?

Comment: Rather than loop, the simplest way for this application would  be to merely repeat each function for each path. (I've edited the answer showing this)

Comment: Great! Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I like the idea with creating a `polyline` and checking points by `getPointAtLength` — really nice. But the OOP is really poor here, why repeating same code for each city and not use one common function for this?

Answer (score 9):

You can also do this just using masks as so:

```css
.paths {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dasharray: 5;
}

.mask {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 830 500" >
  <defs>
    <path id="first" d="M234.3,119c-31-0.7-95,9-128.7,50.8"/>
    <path id="vienna" d="M382.8,243.8c2.9-36.1,15.8-110.3,110.1-145.4"/>
    <path id="budapest" d="M550.6,319.4c34-2.7,109-2.1,174.8,50.5"/>
    <path id="salzburg" d="M265,323c21.5,12.1,57.2,39.5,60.7,85.1"/>
    <path id="tyrol" d="M147.8,319.5c-27.1,7-79.7,31.3-92.8,74.2"/>
    <mask id="first-mask"><use class="mask" xlink:href="#first" /></mask>
    <mask id="vienna-mask"><use class="mask" xlink:href="#vienna" /></mask>
    <mask id="budapest-mask"><use class="mask" xlink:href="#budapest" /></mask>
    <mask id="salzburg-mask"><use class="mask" xlink:href="#salzburg" /></mask>
    <mask id="tyrol-mask"><use class="mask" xlink:href="#tyrol" /></mask>
  </defs>
  <g class="paths">
    <use xlink:href="#first" mask="url(#first-mask)" />
    <use xlink:href="#vienna" mask="url(#vienna-mask)" />
    <use xlink:href="#budapest" mask="url(#budapest-mask)" />
    <use xlink:href="#salzburg" mask="url(#salzburg-mask)" />
    <use xlink:href="#tyrol" mask="url(#tyrol-mask)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

This is also available as:

- [codepen of single dotted path](https://codepen.io/elliz/pen/prYqwx)
- [codepen of these plane tracks](https://codepen.io/elliz/pen/dmYdNb)

Enjoy!

But note ... make sure you test your code cross-browser and fall back to animate tags or javascript if you have issues.

Comment: If you have lines of wildly differing lengths then you would need to either a) set css manually on each one with stroke-dasharray and offset to their approx length + fudge ... or b) use js to get their length, but then just animate the mask ... ;)

Comment: This is the best answer on the web!

Comment: @Ruskin Can you help me in this ticket -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132275/animate-dotted-line-in-svg

Comment: @Meivel, I'll have a look, sure, but cannot promise anything.

Comment: @Ruskin Thanks in advance. Can you post your answer if you get something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to add stroke-dasharray to your animation and lower the dash array in your css. An updated version of your codepen; http://codepen.io/harvey89/pen/NpaWBE

```
stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
stroke-dasharray: 10;

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 10;
  }
}
```

You'll probably have to play around with numbers to get your desired effect though

Comment: The problem is, that the path is not »growing«. It's just animating the dashed line.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://codepen.io/harvey89/pen/NpaWBE

.path {
      stroke-dasharray: 10;
      stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
      animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-dasharray: 0;
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this issue and found a solution. It may work for you.
**Note:** You will need to reverse your shape, i.e., interchange the start and end points.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
path {
stroke-dasharray: 1000;
stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
animation: dash 300ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
to {
stroke-dasharray: 2, 2;
stroke-dashoffset: 2;
}
}


</style>


</head>
<body >
<svg viewBox="0 0 160 100">
  <path d="M48,20 Q48,5 32,0" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="2,2"></path>
 </svg>
</body>

</html>
```