# d3 draw line using stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg

I have a line chart and I want to have an effect like drawing the line from left to right.

I've managed to understand this using stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset. This works as I want given the other settings configured.

```
var path = vis.append(‘svg:path’)
 .attr(‘d’, line(lineData))
 .attr(‘stroke’, ‘blue’)
 .attr(‘stroke-width’, 2)
 .attr(‘fill’, ‘none’);

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
     .attr(“stroke-dasharray”, totalLength + “ “ + totalLength)
     .attr(“stroke-dashoffset”, totalLength)
     .transition()
     .duration(5000)
     .ease(“linear”)
     .attr(“stroke-dashoffset”, 0);
```

My question is, what if I'd like to have the same effect on a dashed line?

Because `stroke-dasharray` needs to be used to make a the line into a dashed line (e.g. (3,3)), the combination of `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` will get confused.

What would be the simplest way to make the effect of drawing a dashed line from left to right?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808756/animate-dashed-svg-line

Comment: Thanks, I've solve the problem.