# Animate dotted line in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I need to animate the dotted line in SVG.

My Work

```css
.paths {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-dasharray: 1440;
  stroke-width: 1440;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.mask {
  fill: #000000;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 1440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1440;
  animation: dash 1s linear alternate infinite;
}

/* does not work in IE, need JS to animate there */
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1440;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1440px" height="273px" viewBox="0 0 1440 273">
  <defs>
    <path id="path1" d="M1123.32761,257.775194 C1125.31269,257.911714 1127.29919,258.015386 1129.28728,258.086416 L1129.21587,260.08514 C1127.20586,260.013327 1125.19742,259.908511 1123.19039,259.770481 L1123.32761,257.775194 Z M1149.15549,257.721324 L1149.29867,259.716193 C1147.28887,259.860436 1145.28109,259.97275 1143.27514,260.052933 L1143.19526,258.054529 C1145.18004,257.975192 1147.16672,257.864058 1149.15549,257.721324 Z M1103.59895,255.321644 C1105.56049,255.675785 1107.52304,255.996909 1109.48673,256.285221 L1109.1962,258.264006 C1107.21086,257.972516 1105.2267,257.647856 1103.24361,257.289824 L1103.59895,255.321644 Z M1168.88749,255.288356 L1169.23041,257.258739 C1167.24336,257.604557 1165.25882,257.920261 1163.27658,258.20567 L1162.99155,256.226084 C1164.95438,255.94347 1166.91962,255.630836 1168.88749,255.288356 Z M1188.35409,250.958394 L1188.87533,252.889276 C1186.92607,253.415479 1184.97988,253.913788 1183.03651,254.384054 L1182.56612,252.440158 C1184.49241,251.974026 1186.42164,251.480057 1188.35409,250.958394 Z M1084.25085,250.741977 C1086.16784,251.304314 1088.08548,251.834299 1090.00388,252.332124 L1089.50152,254.268004 C1087.56281,253.764911 1085.62497,253.229342 1083.68788,252.661108 L1084.25085,250.741977 Z M1207.33821,244.987822 L1208.01252,246.870721 C1206.11001,247.55205 1204.21122,248.207832 1202.31583,248.837965 L1201.68487,246.9401 C1203.56568,246.314814 1205.45002,245.664022 1207.33821,244.987822 Z M1225.85178,237.605501 L1226.65478,239.437218 C1224.80575,240.247808 1222.96117,241.035193 1221.12065,241.799335 L1220.35377,239.952207 C1222.18212,239.193112 1224.01467,238.410864 1225.85178,237.605501 Z M1243.87525,229.045179 L1244.78457,230.826511 C1242.98505,231.74511 1241.19088,232.642521 1239.40158,233.518781 L1238.52195,231.722604 C1240.30125,230.85124 1242.08553,229.958778 1243.87525,229.045179 Z M1261.42046,219.519613 L1262.41643,221.253983 C1260.66426,222.260177 1258.91857,223.246868 1257.17875,224.214204 L1256.20687,222.466219 C1257.93857,221.503395 1259.67624,220.521243 1261.42046,219.519613 Z M1627.26914,207.80897 L1629.21956,208.251526 C1628.78078,210.185312 1628.32001,212.137365 1627.83724,214.107688 L1625.8947,213.631731 C1626.37476,211.672456 1626.83291,209.731535 1627.26914,207.80897 Z M1278.49891,209.229407 L1279.56454,210.921868 C1277.85538,211.998018 1276.1542,213.055892 1274.46021,214.0958 L1273.41387,212.39134 C1275.10136,211.355425 1276.79611,210.30155 1278.49891,209.229407 Z M1295.23872,198.284184 L1296.35974,199.940482 C1294.68797,201.071972 1293.02633,202.185759 1291.3737,203.282419 L1290.26786,201.615952 C1291.91537,200.522688 1293.57195,199.41229 1295.23872,198.284184 Z M1631.0542,188.234904 L1633.02987,188.545938 C1632.72173,190.503182 1632.38775,192.481868 1632.02793,194.481999 L1630.05953,194.127881 C1630.41679,192.141994 1630.74835,190.177668 1631.0542,188.234904 Z M1311.61721,186.87165 L1312.78098,188.498197 C1311.13598,189.67516 1309.50454,190.833846 1307.88488,191.975337 L1306.73273,190.340547 C1308.34847,189.201819 1309.97604,188.045879 1311.61721,186.87165 Z M1327.75521,175.071146 L1328.95067,176.674541 C1327.32647,177.885519 1325.72185,179.075558 1324.1336,180.24687 L1322.94653,178.637255 L1324.53753,177.461706 L1327.75521,175.071146 Z M1633.33305,168.458621 L1635.32824,168.597179 C1635.19105,170.572731 1635.02291,172.573908 1634.82383,174.600715 L1632.8334,174.405206 C1633.03064,172.397228 1633.19718,170.415032 1633.33305,168.458621 Z M1343.68311,163.015316 L1344.90005,164.602477 L1342.49631,166.442409 L1340.13663,168.242262 L1338.9251,166.650976 L1342.4767,163.939546 C1342.87684,163.633261 1343.27894,163.325215 1343.68311,163.015316 Z M1359.51238,150.772551 L1360.74098,152.350697 L1356.00685,156.030684 L1354.78072,154.450624 L1359.51238,150.772551 Z M1635.61723,148.48601 C1635.70897,150.466726 1635.76293,152.478657 1635.77913,154.521803 L1633.77919,154.537655 C1633.7632,152.519891 1633.70992,150.533521 1633.61937,148.578547 L1635.61723,148.48601 Z M1375.26677,138.480722 L1376.49701,140.057593 L1371.77398,143.744201 L1370.54315,142.167795 L1375.26677,138.480722 Z M1633.19245,128.479647 C1633.59284,130.427096 1633.94681,132.412826 1634.25438,134.436827 L1632.27708,134.737305 C1631.97467,132.747302 1631.62678,130.795675 1631.23342,128.882414 L1633.19245,128.479647 Z M1391.04874,126.226714 L1392.26974,127.810752 L1388.5058,130.718451 C1388.18339,130.968027 1387.85859,131.219581 1387.53123,131.473233 L1386.30624,129.892286 L1390.12519,126.939006 C1390.43491,126.700001 1390.74271,126.46261 1391.04874,126.226714 Z M1406.98073,114.102279 L1408.17977,115.703003 L1405.80923,117.483552 L1403.39122,119.309342 L1402.18411,117.714697 L1404.60612,115.885892 L1406.98073,114.102279 Z M1627.19129,109.230023 C1627.98998,111.065414 1628.73295,112.946826 1629.42021,114.874221 L1627.53639,115.545951 C1626.86425,113.660973 1626.13792,111.821687 1625.3574,110.028055 L1627.19129,109.230023 Z M1423.15144,102.260561 L1424.31262,103.88895 L1421.89948,105.617432 L1419.45083,107.386531 L1418.27638,105.767683 L1419.50857,104.875594 L1421.9458,103.122221 C1422.34909,102.833352 1422.75095,102.546143 1423.15144,102.260561 Z M1616.89406,91.8265019 C1618.13872,93.4196688 1619.32194,95.0639875 1620.44368,96.7594041 L1618.77571,97.8629848 C1617.68288,96.2112645 1616.53032,94.6095503 1615.31801,93.0577883 L1616.89406,91.8265019 Z M1439.66882,90.8937273 L1440.77103,92.5625997 C1439.13002,93.6464073 1437.47001,94.7577896 1435.78903,95.8978018 L1434.66647,94.2425514 C1436.35412,93.0980136 1438.02091,91.9820924 1439.66882,90.8937273 Z M1456.65814,80.262159 L1457.67166,81.9863339 C1455.97755,82.9821795 1454.26607,84.009305 1452.53577,85.0682626 L1451.49176,83.36238 C1453.23205,82.2973056 1454.95369,81.2640836 1456.65814,80.262159 Z M1602.43466,77.6278689 C1604.06185,78.8604769 1605.62973,80.1429259 1607.13827,81.4752008 L1605.81435,82.9742797 C1604.3435,81.6752891 1602.81441,80.4245689 1601.22701,79.2221036 L1602.43466,77.6278689 Z M-78.5464409,80.1810759 L-77.8041165,82.0382121 L-78.0837087,82.1500046 L-78.8264397,80.2930311 L-78.5464409,80.1810759 Z M-59.9314676,72.9002172 L-59.2171165,74.7682917 C-61.0774103,75.4796676 -62.94244,76.1978128 -64.8122056,76.9227274 L-64.8122056,76.9227274 L-65.5351776,75.0579723 C-63.6625459,74.3319465 -61.7946426,73.6126948 -59.9314676,72.9002172 L-59.9314676,72.9002172 Z M1474.30911,70.7113881 L1475.18977,72.5070587 C1473.43084,73.3697016 1471.65526,74.269521 1469.86186,75.2067311 L1468.93554,73.4341807 C1470.74389,72.4891567 1472.53469,71.5816295 1474.30911,70.7113881 Z M1584.99313,67.326038 C1586.85734,68.1749035 1588.67051,69.0668343 1590.43261,70.0018452 L1589.49516,71.7685356 C1587.76896,70.8525762 1585.99202,69.9784658 1584.16432,69.1462191 L1584.99313,67.326038 Z M-41.1584271,65.8923933 L-40.4742965,67.7717457 C-42.3455906,68.4529428 -44.2218471,69.1412323 -46.1030658,69.836614 L-46.1030658,69.836614 L-46.7964965,67.9606732 C-44.9121861,67.2641486 -43.0328296,66.574722 -41.1584271,65.8923933 L-41.1584271,65.8923933 Z M1492.79726,62.7886941 L1493.47778,64.6693575 C1491.64083,65.3340569 1489.7873,66.0444582 1487.9162,66.8004971 L1487.16693,64.9461517 C1489.06054,64.1810176 1490.93698,63.461837 1492.79726,62.7886941 Z M1566.11753,60.654598 C1568.09433,61.181211 1570.02926,61.7431318 1571.92229,62.3403751 L1571.32054,64.2477015 C1569.45651,63.6596076 1567.55056,63.1061016 1565.60269,62.5871982 L1566.11753,60.654598 Z M-22.2844901,59.2040051 L-21.6329904,61.0949171 C-23.5150223,61.7433573 -25.4022596,62.3992362 -27.2947021,63.062554 L-27.2947021,63.062554 L-27.9562584,61.1751369 C-26.060473,60.5106474 -24.1698836,59.8536035 -22.2844901,59.2040051 L-22.2844901,59.2040051 Z M1512.1888,57.3379301 L1512.57061,59.3011476 C1510.65566,59.6735671 1508.72396,60.1027581 1506.77461,60.5883876 L1506.29114,58.6477033 C1508.27385,58.1537626 1510.23944,57.7170436 1512.1888,57.3379301 Z M1546.35809,56.751561 C1548.3801,57.0280411 1550.36791,57.3332852 1552.32152,57.6673018 L1551.98447,59.6386955 C1550.05299,59.3084646 1548.08722,59.0066041 1546.08714,58.7331227 L1546.35809,56.751561 Z M1532.30429,55.4965393 L1532.26735,57.4961982 C1530.30361,57.45993 1528.32339,57.492429 1526.32588,57.5930941 L1526.22521,55.595629 C1528.26825,55.49267 1530.29435,55.4594179 1532.30429,55.4965393 Z M341.468329,52.2749039 C343.202397,53.2872484 344.921385,54.3211941 346.625292,55.37674 L346.625292,55.37674 L345.572045,57.0769369 C343.882995,56.0305948 342.178977,55.0056537 340.459989,54.0021127 L340.459989,54.0021127 Z M-3.30069717,52.8580177 L-2.68453709,54.7607386 C-4.57748934,55.3737353 -6.47591122,55.9945475 -8.37980267,56.6231753 L-8.37980267,56.6231753 L-9.0068667,54.7240201 C-7.09935092,54.0941955 -5.19729443,53.4721947 -3.30069717,52.8580177 L-3.30069717,52.8580177 Z M15.798896,46.8817504 L16.3766682,48.7964774 C14.4716779,49.3713115 12.5609239,49.9543804 10.6444061,50.5456841 L10.6444061,50.5456841 L10.0547717,48.6345767 C11.975232,48.0420567 13.8899401,47.4577812 15.798896,46.8817504 L15.798896,46.8817504 Z M323.687712,42.9011856 C325.506396,43.7626404 327.310268,44.6453372 329.099326,45.5492758 L329.099326,45.5492758 L328.197395,47.3343588 C326.423517,46.4380897 324.634906,45.5628608 322.831561,44.7086717 L322.831561,44.7086717 Z M35.0479454,41.2985098 L35.583826,43.2253809 C33.6679805,43.7581953 31.7460571,44.2996916 29.8180561,44.8498701 L29.8180561,44.8498701 L29.2692401,42.9266434 C31.20154,42.3752382 33.127775,41.832527 35.0479454,41.2985098 L35.0479454,41.2985098 Z M54.4137086,36.1554872 L54.9038177,38.0945057 C52.9760606,38.5817684 51.0418747,39.0782129 49.1012602,39.5838393 L49.1012602,39.5838393 L48.5969961,37.6484536 C50.5423146,37.1416016 52.4812187,36.643946 54.4137086,36.1554872 L54.4137086,36.1554872 Z M305.208518,35.0703932 C307.091705,35.7792274 308.960599,36.5085766 310.815199,37.2584411 L310.815199,37.2584411 L310.065506,39.1126151 C308.225906,38.3688152 306.372062,37.6453394 304.503972,36.9421878 L304.503972,36.9421878 Z M73.8034822,31.5145207 L74.2436816,33.4654755 C72.3025074,33.9034681 70.3545091,34.3512054 68.3996867,34.8086875 L68.3996867,34.8086875 L67.9439456,32.8613046 C69.9039324,32.4026139 71.8571112,31.9536859 73.8034822,31.5145207 L73.8034822,31.5145207 Z M286.127378,28.7316532 C288.059932,29.2922946 289.978841,29.8725317 291.884104,30.4723651 L291.884104,30.4723651 L291.283506,32.3800555 C289.392675,31.7847656 287.488222,31.2088996 285.570145,30.6524581 L285.570145,30.6524581 Z M93.4176489,27.374151 L93.8026966,29.3367356 C91.8508972,29.7196674 89.8918554,30.1129389 87.9255713,30.5165504 L87.9255713,30.5165504 L87.5234237,28.5573982 C89.4953898,28.1526204 91.4601315,27.7582046 93.4176489,27.374151 L93.4176489,27.374151 Z M266.670617,23.8473546 C268.642665,24.2687694 270.601741,24.708821 272.547842,25.1675104 L272.547842,25.1675104 L272.089022,27.11417 C270.15654,26.6586908 268.211088,26.2216993 266.252666,25.8031963 L266.252666,25.8031963 Z M113.12364,23.81784 L113.447966,25.791368 C111.485224,26.1139209 109.514773,26.4474775 107.536613,26.7920379 L107.536613,26.7920379 L107.193416,24.821704 C109.177847,24.4760513 111.154588,24.1414299 113.12364,23.81784 L113.12364,23.81784 Z M132.960422,20.8973251 L133.217567,22.8807253 C131.248015,23.1360758 129.270265,23.4031229 127.284319,23.681867 L127.284319,23.681867 L127.006327,21.7012811 C128.9992,21.4215647 130.983898,21.1535793 132.960422,20.8973251 L132.960422,20.8973251 Z M246.908397,20.3110525 C248.903634,20.601611 250.886667,20.9097036 252.857495,21.2353313 L252.857495,21.2353313 L252.531468,23.2085789 C250.573255,22.8850357 248.602828,22.5789014 246.620185,22.290177 L246.620185,22.290177 Z M152.90331,18.6843349 L153.086024,20.6759712 C151.109111,20.8573348 149.123449,21.0511805 147.129037,21.2575088 L147.129037,21.2575088 L146.923229,19.2681263 C148.925315,19.061004 150.918676,18.8664067 152.90331,18.6843349 L152.90331,18.6843349 Z M226.963564,18.0248091 C228.970843,18.1950729 230.966703,18.3817432 232.951143,18.5848206 L232.951143,18.5848206 L232.747536,20.5744297 C230.774638,20.3725334 228.790301,20.1869408 226.794525,20.0176527 L226.794525,20.0176527 Z M172.896989,17.2589283 L172.997287,19.2564118 C171.013922,19.3560012 169.021191,19.4689474 167.019095,19.5952506 L167.019095,19.5952506 L166.893175,17.5992185 C168.903786,17.4723781 170.905058,17.3589478 172.896989,17.2589283 L172.896989,17.2589283 Z M206.992853,16.8834341 C209.00573,16.9447694 211.007928,17.0214428 212.999449,17.1134549 L212.999449,17.1134549 L212.907144,19.1113237 C210.92611,19.0197961 208.934375,18.9435234 206.931939,18.8825063 L206.931939,18.8825063 Z M192.934298,16.7036306 L192.943239,18.7036107 C190.958051,18.7124854 188.962846,18.7356444 186.957622,18.7730881 L186.957622,18.7730881 L186.920283,16.7734367 C188.934948,16.7358167 190.939619,16.7125478 192.934298,16.7036306 L192.934298,16.7036306 Z" />
    <mask id="mask1">
      <use class="mask" xlink:href="#path1">
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use class="paths" xlink:href="#path1" mask="url(#mask1)" />
</svg>
```

Below is the reference I have added I need my SVG starts to its animation from the right side and end left side. It will be once or infinity that has been controlled with the CSS animation.

[Reference](https://codepen.io/lorryc/pen/pjwEJK)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is you have a series of rectangles filled in the shape of the dashes, rather than a single line that is dashed. You are animating the paths of those fake dashes, not the lines that you think. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808756/animate-dashed-svg-line/42931673 for inspiration. Try creating a single line along the path you want to paint.

Comment: @Ruskin Thanks for the suggestion. I'll update the line and work on the animations.

Comment: no worries ... you cannot learn without mistakes. I deconstructed the `d` attribute on your path, putting each `z M` onto a new line. They mark the end of one path and the beginning of another. You may also find https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ a good tool when you get to optimising your svgs