# How could I animate dotted stroke SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I animate the second stroke that have dotted line like the first stroke that it's animating but without losing the dotted stroke? I want the stroke to be dotted but when i set the `stroke-dasharray` the stroke becomes linear.

I am pretty new to svg's so I don't know how to do it.Thank you!

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

#stroke {
  stroke-dasharray: 1950;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1950;
  animation: anim 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
  stroke-dashoffset: 1950;
  }
  
  100% {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
 <svg width="1228" height="494" viewBox="0 0 1228 494" fill="none">
 <path id="stroke" d="M1008.5 54C1053.67 28.1667 1157.7 -26.9001 1188.5 19.4999C1219.3 65.8999 1227 239.167 1227 320C1225.17 379 1184 495.3 1034 488.5C846.5 480 785.5 510 683.5 474.5C601.9 446.1 620.167 402 639.5 383.5C656.833 372.5 693.2 357.1 700 383.5C708.5 416.5 631.5 474.5 562.5 474.5C507.3 474.5 270.833 474.5 159.5 474.5" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="6 6"/>
 </svg>
 
  <svg width="1228" height="494" viewBox="0 0 1228 494" fill="none">
 <path d="M1008.5 54C1053.67 28.1667 1157.7 -26.9001 1188.5 19.4999C1219.3 65.8999 1227 239.167 1227 320C1225.17 379 1184 495.3 1034 488.5C846.5 480 785.5 510 683.5 474.5C601.9 446.1 620.167 402 639.5 383.5C656.833 372.5 693.2 357.1 700 383.5C708.5 416.5 631.5 474.5 562.5 474.5C507.3 474.5 270.833 474.5 159.5 474.5" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="6 6"/>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate dashed SVG line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808756/animate-dashed-svg-line)

Comment: I want something more simple.I think it's too much JS for a simple task like this

Comment: You can use the same path as a mask for the animated one. The one inside the mask would have a white dashed stroke