# Animate SVG path to look like a flowing pipe

Tags: animation, svg, css-animations, mask

I'd like to use SVG and CSS to create a "flowing pipe" animation. I want to recreate the effect seen here: https://twitter.com/JohnPhamous/status/1732463692443512981

I got the basic SVG structure (I think), but can't figure out how to animate the mask x position! I've tried all sort of CSS properties but no luck. Any thoughts?

```css
.svg-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}

.svg-container svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* How to translate the mask? */
#gradient-mask {
  mask-position: 50% 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <!--  background gray line  -->
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <path d="M 0,50 Q 50,0 100,50 T 200,50" stroke="lightgray" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <!--  foreground blue line  -->
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <!-- white shows, black hides-->
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
        <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
        <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
      </linearGradient>

      <mask id="gradient-mask">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)" />
      </mask>
    </defs>

    <path d="M 0,50 Q 50,0 100,50 T 200,50" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="none" mask="url(#gradient-mask)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd start by looking at SMIL animations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform or CSS animations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808756/animate-dashed-svg-line/42931673#42931673. Look forward to seeing your working version.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working :). I used svg `<linearGradient>` and `<mask>`.

The animation is on the `x` attribute of the `mask`

```css
.container {
  width: 945px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container svg {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

@keyframes slideMask {
  from {
    x: -100%;
  }
  to {
    x: 100%;
  }
}

.container .mask-rect {
  animation: slideMask 5s ease infinite;
}

.big-box {
  width: 6rem;
  height: 11rem;
  background: #edebeb;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 8rem;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #292929;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background: #edebeb;
  position: absolute;
  color: #292929;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box.first {
  top: -2rem;
}

.box.second {
  top: 6rem;
}

.box.third {
  top: 15rem;
}

.box.fourth {
  bottom: -2rem
    ;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <!--  background  -->
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 496 215" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M496 91C374.38 91 121.129 1 -9 1" stroke="#EDEBEB" />
    <path d="M495 113C373.62 113 120.871 68 -9 68" stroke="#EDEBEB" />
    <path d="M495 129C375.788 129 127.552 151 0 151" stroke="#EDEBEB" />
    <path d="M495 143C375.788 143 127.552 214 0 214" stroke="#EDEBEB" />
  </svg>
  <!--  foreground  -->
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 496 215" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <!-- white shows, black hides-->
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
        <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
        <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
      </linearGradient>

      <mask id="gradient-mask">
        <rect class="mask-rect" x="-50%" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <path d="M496 91C374.38 91 121.129 1 -9 1" stroke="#FB5844" mask="url(#gradient-mask)" />
    <path d="M495 113C373.62 113 120.871 68 -9 68" stroke="#E6FF02" mask="url(#gradient-mask)" />
    <path d="M495 129C375.788 129 127.552 151 0 151" stroke="#02B0FF" mask="url(#gradient-mask)" />
    <path d="M495 143C375.788 143 127.552 214 0 214" stroke="#7832B6" mask="url(#gradient-mask)" />
  </svg>
  <div class="big-box">Z</div>
  <div class="box first">A</div>
  <div class="box second">B</div>
  <div class="box third">C</div>
  <div class="box fourth">D</div>

</div>
```